# Find an integral using the convolution function property

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, convolution

I want to prove the identity

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x }{x}\frac{\sin(x /2)}{x / 2}dx = \pi 
$$

I think I can use here the following proposition, that can be easily proved using Fubini theorem:
$$f, g \in L_1(\Bbb{R}) : \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}gdx = 1 \Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(f * g)(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$$

We know that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \pi$$
So can we find function $$g \in L_1(\Bbb{R}): (f * g)(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sin (x / 2)}{x/2}, \: \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}gdx = 1 ?$$

Maybe Fourier transform could be useful here ?

Comment: You may find [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral) interesting (it is applicable since your integrand is even and you can write $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\;dx =2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\;dx$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x }{x}\frac{\sin\frac x2}{\frac x2}dx
$$
$$
=-4\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin x \sin \frac x2 d(\frac1x)
$$
$$
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4\cos x\sin\frac x2+2\sin x\cos \frac x2 }{x}dx
$$

$$
=\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{3 \sin\frac{3x}2 - \sin \frac x2 }{x}dx
$$
$$
=(3-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t }{t}dt=\pi
$$
where $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t }{t}dt=\frac\pi2$ is used.